# Fall back to pattern lock if fingerprint not recognised

Tags: samsung, lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-6, pattern-lock

Can I make my phone fall back to pattern lock (instead of password) if the fingerprint isn't recognised? I've got a Samsung Galaxy S6 with the stock rom, Android version 5.1.1. Ideally I'd like a way of doing this without rooting the device.

Comment: If you're willing to fall back to pattern, why use the fingerprint at all? Is it more convenient? (I'm assuming you know that if you did do this, you'd be giving up any security benefit of fingerprint locking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have seen yourself, that is not the standard procedure. Hence, if you like to have that I would suggest to have a look at Trust Agents (Smart Lock feature uses them). You probably could write your own Trust Agent app that checks for failed fingerprint authentications and then call the pattern authentication.